# Oracle Apex Pivot sorting

Tags: oracle, pivot, report, oracle-apex, interactive

I have an interactive report, which using Pivot, but I was trying to custom sort the report by row column of pivot "Age Group", but I couldn't.

[image]

I need this report in such this sorting:

[image]

How I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd want to sort by the first digit(s), and then by `age_group` itself (as a string). Something like this (sample data in lines #1 - 10; query you might be interested in begins at line #11):

```
SQL> with test (age_group) as
  2    (select 'wahine 45-64'   from dual union all
  3     select 'wahine 25-44'   from dual union all
  4     select 'rangtahi 15-24' from dual union all
  5     select 'pepis 0_4'      from dual union all
  6     select 'pakeke 45-64'   from dual union all
  7     select 'pakeke 25-44'   from dual union all
  8     select 'N/A'            from dual union all
  9     select 'kuia 65+'       from dual
 10    )
 11  select age_group
 12  from test
 13  order by to_number(regexp_substr(age_group, '\d+')), age_group;

AGE_GROUP
--------------
pepis 0_4
rangtahi 15-24
pakeke 25-44
wahine 25-44
pakeke 45-64
wahine 45-64
kuia 65+
N/A

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```